# Can I get content of Xml Root as string using standart xml serialization?

Tags: .net, xml

For example there is an xml-document like

```
<document>
  <id>some_id</id>
  <name>some name</name>
  <content>
    <table>
      ...     
    </table>
  </content>
</document>
```

There is a class Document to deserialize the document using XmlSerializer

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "document")]
public class Document
{
  [XmlElement(ElementName = "id")]
  public long Id { get; set;}

  [XmlElement(ElementName = "name")]
  public string Name { get; set;}

  [???]
  public string Content { get; set;}
}
```

Then I get an instance of Document using XmlSerializer.Deserilize. What can I do to get value of the Content property equals `<table>...</table>` ?

Answer (score 0):

Normally: *you wouldn't* - you would create types that map the entire hive; however, if this is used for ad-hoc contents, you can use `XmlElement` as the type, i.e.

```cs
  [XmlElement("content")]
  public XmlElement Content { get; set;}
```

and then access the `.InnerXml`, `.InnerText`, or `.OuterXml` of that